# Creating a task pipeline with .NET 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, pipeline, task-parallel-library

I want to upload a file in chunks to a web service.

```
// Web service method:
void UploadFile(int fileId, byte[] chunk, int position, bool complete);
```

Using .NET 4 task parallel library, I want to upload a file, one chunk at a time.

I've got the byte chunks on the client, and I can upload each one just fine:

```
List<byte[]> chunks = ...;
webService.UploadFileAsyncCompleted += OnChunkUploaded;
foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
   webService.UploadFileAsync(...);
}
```

However, that uploads all chunks simultaneously. I want to upload each chunk, one after the other. A pipeline, if you will.

How can I do this with .NET 4 task parallel library?

Comment: Maybe "Running one task after another in Silverlight" would be a better title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the TPL. Change your method call to webService.UploadFile(...). What you're trying to do is synchronously upload one piece after the other. Why do you need a pipeline?

Comment: I want to do this asynchronously, one after the other. I don't want to call UploadFile, since that would block the UI.

Comment: Not sure what webService is. If you can, have it report progress every N bytes uploaded (e.g. ProgressChanged event) and upload the entire file at once in one async request. In other words, let it deal with the chunking. If that isn't an option, then drop your code (with webService.UploadFile(...)) in an Action<T> and schedule it on a background thread using BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is Silverlight, there is no blocking call. And yes, TPL is available for Silverlight through some CTP bits. In other words, I cannot call the synchronous version, because there is none.

Comment: Fair enough since this is Silverlight. The question remains what class is webService and does it support progress updates? That is going to be your preferred method. TPL is a sledgehammer trying to drive a finishing nail, IMHO. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: It's a WCF web service reference. There's no progress update.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. Wasn't what I was looking for, but you've swayed me. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: If it's a WCF web service reference, take a look at the generated proxy. It's just a bunch of hidden C# code - click Show Hidden Files and the reference should show a +/- expander beside it with a C# file underneath. You can use this as a basis for your own web service proxy that does provide progress updates. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the TPL, I would recommend using a `BackgroundWorker` which was designed for exactly this sort of scenario (performing work in the background of a GUI application). I would then call the synchronous version up UploadFile. The `BackgroundWorker` class allows you to do things like report progress and cancel the operation if you need to.

Comment: +1! Ironically I just wrote the same thing in a comment to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UploadFileAsyncCompleted` event for that.

Fire up the first asynchronous chunk upload. And then have the `UploadFileAsyncCompleted` event handler proceed with the next. Roughly, this:

```
int chunksSent = 0;
webService.UploadFileAsyncCompleted += delegate
{
    chunksSent++;
    if(chunksSent < chunks.Count)
        webService.UploadFileAsync(..., chunk[chunksSent], ...);
};
webService.UploadFileAsync(..., chunk[0], ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a parallel library to do thing sequentially is probably not the best idea. F# and C# 5 CTP both have really good async programming models - but if you're not in a position to use those you're simply going to have to wait for the `UploadFileAsyncCompleted` event to fire before you start uploading the next chunk.